# Tables - cellcolor does not work with tabu any more

Tags: pdftex, luatex, tabu, cellcolor

I wrote a document with colored cells using `\cellcolor` with `tabu`. Unfortunately, it does not work any more. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
Colored table:

\begin{tabular}{l}
    \hline
    \cellcolor{green}Colored\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

Uncolored table although it should be green, too:

\begin{tabu} to \columnwidth {l}
    \hline
    \cellcolor{green}Colored\\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the MWE]

I'm using the following `LuaTeX` version:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX)  (format=lualatex 2020.1.30)  4 FEB 2020 12:20
```

and tested it additionaly with `pdflatex`:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.1.30)  4 FEB 2020 12:12
```

Any ideas, how to fix this?

Comment: Read the readme and the issues here: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/

Comment: The simplest way to fix this is to _not_ using tabu. It was a promising package, but unfortunately, the author lost interest in it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I didn't realise this state of development.

Answer (score 1):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package. You can easily set colors for cells, rows or columns with `tblr` environment:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  width = 0.5\linewidth,
  colspec = {|X|X|},
}
  \hline
  \SetCell{teal8} Colored & \SetCell{blue8} Colored \\
  \hline
  \SetRow{purple8} Colored & Colored                \\
  \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]